# how to get variable in testcase pass from Command line argument in Robot framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

in below Example, I want to get url from Command prompt

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***

*** Test Cases ***
TestModule
    Launch webpage

*** Keywords ***
Launch webpage
    Open Browser    $[url]  chrome
    Wait Until Page Contains  Amazon.in
    Close Browser
```

Comment: The user guide shows how to set variables from the command line. Is there something about the description that doesn't make sense to you? Have you tried doing what's in the user guide?

Comment: i am able to pass from command line but some problem i test case i am getting error invalid aurgument

Comment: Please show the exact error message, and the command you are using that causes the error.

Answer (score 2):

the way to use robotframework cmd variables is the following:
robot --variable EXAMPLE:value path/to/test

so in your case:

robot --variable url:<url_value> path/to/test

your code should look like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***

*** Test Cases ***
TestModule
    Launch webpage

*** Keywords ***
Launch webpage
    Open Browser    ${url}  chrome
    Wait Until Page Contains  Amazon.in
    Close Browser
```

Comment: There appears to be something wrong with your answer. Why do you have `*** Setings *** Library  SeleniumLibrary` as part of the command line? That isn't valid.